# Unit testing in Embedded C - Testing modules with references to SDK

Tags: c, unit-testing, embedded, tdd

I create a project for a microcontroller by programming it in C language. Due to its specificity (a microcontroller with a built-in BLE core), I have to use the SDK and a specific project template. How can I test my modules when they have numerous references to other files (modules) in the SDK? (References are needed to use functions to, for example, send data via BLE) Do I have to somehow mock each of the SDK functions? I am using Unity test framework.
Module example:

### my_module.c

```
#include "sdk_module_1.h"
#include "my_module.h"

void init_hardware(void)
{
   //function code
}
bool send_data(int data)
{ 
   //prepare data eq.
   data++ 
   //send data using SDK function (sdk_module_1.h)
   return send_data(data);
}
```

### my_module.h

```
  void init_hardware(void)
  void send_data(int data)
```

### my_module_test.c

```
  #include "my_module.h"
  #include  "//unity files" 
  TEST_SETUP(Test)
  {   

  }
  TEST_TEAR_DOWN(Test)
  {

  }
  TEST(Test, First_test)
  {
     TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(send_data(5),true);
  }
```

When I try to test my module, I have a problem with referencing SDK modules and their functions. How can I create tests for such software? Should I change the way my modules are written?

Comment: You did not include your test code in your question.

Comment: My method with embedded C code was to 'patch' anything specific to the controller, so that a model of it would run on a PC. Then the general parts of the code can be more easily debugged and tested. Ideally, everything processor-specific is kept away from the general functionality. This gives a heads-up to problems that are unrelated to the hardware, and makes it easier to diagnose faults that are related to the "OS" or the hardware itself. With a different compiler, but still an invaluable assurance technique.

Comment: @WeatherVane So should I use controllers to separate the SDK functions? So that I can connect mocks there instead of the functions from the SDK?

Comment: I wasn't using your environment, but yes, I mocked everything that was hardware specific, and the supposed device data streams too. Another reason for this was that it was no "ideal world" where I would get fault-free hardware with plenty of time to prove the code. The harsh reality was that a board would be delivered (possibly with faults) too late to have the software tested and ready in time, and I would have to be able to *prove* that any hardware faults were that.

Answer (score 0):

The resource you want is [James Grenning](http://blog.wingman-sw.com/)'s [Test Driven Development for Embedded C](https://wingman-sw.com/test-driven-development-for-embedded-c-book).

(Note: what follows below is a translation of my ideas into C.  If you find a conflict with Grenning's approach, try his first - he has a lot more laps in the embedded space than I do.)

---

> How can I test my modules when they have numerous references to other files (modules) in the SDK?

Sometimes the answer is that you have to change your design.  In other words, treating testability as a design constraint, rather than an afterthought.

The way I normally describe it is this: we want to design our code such that (a) all the complicated code is easy to test and (b) anything that's hard to test is "so simple there are obviously no deficiencies".

This often means designing our code so that collaborations between complicated code and hard to test code are configurable, allowing you to provide a substitute implementation (stub/mock/test double) when using the real thing isn't cost effective.

So instead of having A (complicated) directly invoke B (hard for testing), we might instead have A invoke B via a function pointer that, during testing, can be replaced with a pointer to a simpler function.

(In some styles, this gets reversed: the complicated logic points to an inert/stub implementation by default, and you opt in to using the complicated implementation instead.)

In other words, we replace

```
void A(void) {
   B(); // B is the function that makes things hard to test.
}
```

with

```
void A(void) {
   C(&B);
}

# It's been a long time, please forgive (or correct) the spelling here
void C( void (*fn)()) {
   &fn();
}
```

We test A by looking at it, agreeing that it is "so simple there are obviously no deficiencies", and signing off on it.  We test C by passing it pointers to substitute implementations, writing as many substitutes as we need for B to ensure that all of C's edge cases are covered.

---

Note that "hard to test" can cover a lot of bases - the real function is slow, the real function is unstable, the real function costs money... if it makes testing less pleasant or less effective, then it counts.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would highly recommend using [Ceedling](http://www.throwtheswitch.org/ceedling) to manage and run your unit tests in C. It wraps Unity and CMock very nicely and makes unit testing, particularly for embedded systems, a lot easier than it otherwise would be.

With regards to unit testing when an SDK is involved, you first need to remember that the point of a unit test is to test a unit, so anything outside of that needs to be mocked or stubbed, otherwise it’s not a unit test and cannot be run as one.

So, for something like an I2C hardware abstraction module, any calls to an underlying SDK (that would ordinarily do the actual I2C transaction) need to be mocked so that you can place expectations on what should happen when the call is made instead of the real thing. In this way, the unit test of the I2C HAL module is exercising only its behaviour and how it handles its calls, and nothing else, as it should.

Therefore, all that you generally need to do to unit test with an SDK is to ensure that any module you use has its public functions mocked. You then simply include the mock in the test, rather than the real module.

Now, I find that you don’t really want to mess with the original SDK and its structure for the purpose of unit testing, and moreover you don’t want to change how the real code includes the real modules, so the problem for the test then comes when the SDK function you’re calling in your code sits behind layers of other modules in the SDK, as is often the case. Here, you don’t want to mock everything you’re not using, but you do need to match the include structure. I’ve found that a good way to do this is simply to create a *support* folder and copy any top-level headers that the code uses from the SDK into it. I then configure the test to include from *support* before it includes from the SDK.

Once you have this kind of structure in place, unit testing with an SDK is easy. Ceedling will help with all of this.